# laravel, show modal after redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to show an information with modal after redirection.
 This is what I do:

Controller:
    return redirect()->route('verification',Auth::user()->id)->with(['code',1]);

verification.blade.php

```
@if(!empty($code) && $code == 1)
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
@endif

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                                <h5 class="modal-title">example</h5>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h6 class="text-semibold text-center">example</h6>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When it redirects, it only goes at the route without showing the modal.
What can I do ?

Comment: What is `$error_code` here?

Comment: Can you try to put `script` in footer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" style="{{Session::has("code") ? Session::get('code')==1 ? "display:block":"" : "display:none"}}">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                                <h5 class="modal-title">example</h5>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h6 class="text-semibold text-center">example</h6>

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Before trying remove those lines :

```
@if(!empty($error_code) && $code == 1)
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use session, like that :

```
// YOUR CODE HERE
session()->flash('code', $yourcodehere);
return redirect()->route('verification', Auth::user()->id);
```

At verification.blade.php

```
// CHECK IF HAS SESSION 
@if (session()->has('code') && session()->get('code') == 1)
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myModal").modal();
  }); 
</script>
@endif
```

Comment: I am trying but this is what i get :"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::set()"

Comment: Oh!!, Try to use flash session, It will show modal one time :)

Comment: I edited code now, If you want to live model msg in your page after redirect, Just use session(['code' => $yourcodehere]);